# Update Asp.Net Core Role Claim

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

How i can change role claim and apply it in terms of one request in Asp.Net Core?
I tried to use

```
_signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);
```

But it only works after refreshing the page. Is there any way to update roles for user and change current principal in one request?

Comment: What exactly means "it works only after refreshing the page". What check if failing and is this check executed after RefreshSignInAsync?

Comment: @ChristophLütjen i mean that new roles validates by default attributes like [Authorize(Roles="NewRole")] only after refreshing the page(cookies needs to be updated) but it there any way to set new principal for request with new role, so that further processing can make use of it?

Comment: Can you post your controller action that does the RefreshSingInAsync and your code that is not working? It would help to be able to understand the full flow...

Answer (score 3):

You could not change the `Current ClaimsPrincipal` directly.

To reflect the new claims, you could try `_signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync`.

To check the new roles in the same request, you may try `User.AddIdentity` to explict add the new role claim to `User`.

```
                var roleName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();                
            var r1 = User.IsInRole(roleName);

            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            var role = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole { Name = roleName });
            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, roleName);

            var claimsPrincipal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);
            var claims = claimsPrincipal.Claims.ToList();

            User.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>() { claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Value == roleName) }));

            var r3 = User.IsInRole(roleName);
```